# Keycloak and Spring Boot - overwrite default /sso/login path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, path, single-sign-on, keycloak

I have a Spring Boot app deployed with the use of Kubernetes/AWS. The application uses Keycloak for authentication. Everything works on my computer. When I hit some URL, the app redirects me to the Keycloak instance's login page.

Nevertheless, my application is deployed on the relative path: `"https://organisation.com/{my_application_name}/"`, so the library redirects me to "`https://organisation.com/sso/login`" instead of "`https://organisation.com/{my_application_name}/sso/login`".

I have read the documentation but I cannot find any relevant option which can fix the issue.

I use this library:

> org.keycloak
>              keycloak-spring-boot-starter

These are my keycloak's settings:

```
keycloak.realm=${REALM_NAME}
keycloak.auth-server-url=${AUTH_URL}
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.resource=${RESOURCE}
keycloak.credentials.secret=${SECRET}
keycloak.confidential-port=0
keycloak.public-client=false
```

Is there any way to overwrite this URL or add a relative path?

Answer (score -2):

```
spring.application.name={my_application_name}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit your answer to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).